# Gunicorn with gevent worker server hangs after some time

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, gunicorn, gevent

I am getting this stacktrace after the server runs for some time
2014-02-12 23:42:14 [28012] [ERROR] Error handling request

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 39, in handle
    self.handle_request(req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 86, in handle_request
    super(GeventWorker, self).handle_request(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 74, in handle_request
    resp.write(item)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 255, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 251, in send_headers
    util.write(self.sock, "%s\r\n" % "".join(tosend))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/util.py", line 235, in write
    sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 509, in sendall
    data_sent += self.send(_get_memory(data, data_sent), flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 483, in send
    return sock.send(data, flags)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I am using gunicorn+nginx as a server. This is my gunicorn configuration:

```
workers = 5
worker_class = 'egg:gunicorn#gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 3600
keepalive = 2
```

I am not even sure if this stacktrace is the actual cause of server hang as 2-3 other get requests are shown after this stacktrace (get requests which work normally when the server is started fresh) and no further logs are produced.

Also after some time I keep getting the error "included urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it". This does not happen when server is started fresh. And I've tested all the urls individually and they seem to work fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us some of your code. We need to see how you're handling socket errors.

Comment: I am not handling any socket errors from code end. Everything is dependent upon gunicorn worker configuration. Is that something I should be doing apart from config?

Comment: If you don't handle socket errors you're going to get unhandled exceptions. It's impossible to help unless you show us the code you're running.

Comment: The code is a ~20k line project. Which part exactly should I show

Comment: I've no idea, but the error is generated from your program writing to a socket that has either been closed or otherwise dropped. So something where you're writing to sockets is probably a good starting point. Is this solely a gevent and gunicorn setup or is there something else running as well that might interfere?

Comment: I am not explicitly connecting/writing to any socket. This is purely gevent+gunicorn serving to my http requests when I face the worker hang. The same project I am able to run smoothly by using runserver instead of gunicorn+gevent(which is not scalable though)